# Can same client have multiple connections to a server?

Tags: tcp

I am developing a client server application.
When I run same client multiple times, server received data from one only and block data from other.
Here my question is,is it valid to make multiple connection on same port from a single client?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. It all depends on how the server side code is written. You could fork () a separate process after you accept a client connection through accept () or you could save all the socket descriptors returned by accept () and handle all of them through select ().

So yes, it is valid to make multiple connections to the same port from the same client. The client would use a different source port so the 4-tuple (src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port) is kept unique.

Comment: I am creating a new thread after each accept for client. If I run multiple clients from same machine, Server creates threads for each client.But server receives the data from latest created client only.It does'nt receive the data from others if sending simultaneously. What I found out that all clients share same socket number.Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: No, each return from accept () should give you a new socket file descriptor.

Comment: Accept is called at Server end and server gets different socket but all clients are getting same socket number.I guess this is not expected behavior.